# AS3 Determine if MovieClip fills another MovieClip completely

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to determine in AS3 Flash if a draggable movieclip on the stage completely fills another movieclip also on the stage. I looked into another StackOverflow article with this code:

`var inter = mcOverlay.getRect(this).intersection(mcLoadedImage.getRect(this));`

```
    if ((inter.width * inter.height) == 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
```

This code uses the intersect method, it works, but I also want to check that the movieclip is completely covered by the draggable movieclip on the stage.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just check if both rects are equal, ie if the left, right, top and bottom are the same.

Comment: OH!! I forgot about those properties! Let me try those out! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use compare each movieclips rect, ie compare the left, right, top and bottom values.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using intersection, use Rectangle.contains.

```
var contains : Boolean = mcContainer.getRect(this).contains(mcContained.getRect(this));
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Rectangle.html#containsRect()

Comment: Thanks! I will also look into this.